# Getting a segmentation fault in C with unsigned long long int?

Tags: c, clion

Im trying to code a decimal to binary converter in C. I have to use unsigned long long int because the largest number I have to be able to calculate is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. On the Linux server my professor has us use, it says there is a segmentation fault, and on CLion debugger it says "Exception = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ff7bc694ff8)" and claims i = {unsigned long long} 18446744073708503289, which isn't right. It does this no matter what number userInput is.

What I currently have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  unsigned long long int userInput;
  unsigned long long int i;
  unsigned long long int binary[] = {};

  printf("Enter a number from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615: ");
  scanf("%lld", &userInput);

  printf("\nThe binary value of %lld is: ", userInput);

  if (userInput == 0)
  {
      printf("0");
  }
  else
  {
    for (i = 0; userInput > 0; i++)
    {
        binary[i] = userInput%2;
        userInput = userInput/2;
    }
    for (i -= 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%lld", binary[i]);
    }
  }

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i -= 1` in your last `for` loop doesn't look right.

Comment: and since 'binary' is meant to be either 0 or 1 long long is a bit of an overkill anyway

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is counting down `i` from the previous loop.

Comment: ..., but `i >= 0` is always true.

Comment: Mellanie Martin, who or what text suggested using  `"%lld"` with `unsigned long long int userInput`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `binary` was not given an explicit size and was given an empty initializer list, the array has size 0.  Any attempt to use such an array will trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this particular case causes a crash.

You need to store up to 64 binary digits, so make the array that size.

```
unsigned long long int binary[64];
```

Another problem is in this conditional:

```
for (i -= 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Because `i` has an `unsigned` type, the condition `i >= 0` will always be true.  So change the type of `i` to `int`.

```
int i;
```

Comment: and is only the bits so it can be char[..]

Comment: When I do that, it still says there's a segmentation fault.

Comment: @MellanieMartin See my edit.  You have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that one of these loops can never terminate:

```c
  unsigned long long int i;
  // ...
  for (i -= 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    printf("%lld", binary[i]);
  }
```

The variable `i` is unsigned and can never be negative. Therefore `i >= 0` will always be true, and it will loop forever, reading memory until it reaches something that memory segmentation does not allow it to read.